# Matlab: change position of ylabel

Tags: matlab, label, axis

I was wondering if it is possible to change the position of the ylabel. I would like to move it down (as suggested on the attached figure) to match it better with the yticks.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way, presuming you want the yticks to stay where they are. you can try using underscore to make subscript, or display yticklabels " " and use text to add the numbers where you want them

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
figure;
yl = ylabel('y axis label');
yl.Position(2) = yl.Position(2) -  0.3;
```

[image]